# my background screen is resizing when bootstrap model is active

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have bootstrap model for accepting login credentials, when i click on login and when model appears, background screen which is my home screen will resize at right end.

I have tried removing extra spaces using no-gutters still it works same.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj80b.png)

Comment: can you have working example of it ?

Comment: @NishargShah i have attached the image, can u please refer it.

Comment: because your some element size is wider than the resolution of your window, check it first